# Jquery Data Table custom binding

Tags: datatables

How to bind the column value in j query data table in below format, I mean final design will looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data)

```html
var table = $('#dt').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: [{
    title: "a",
    data: "a"
  }, {
    title: "b",
    data: "b"
  }, {
    title: "c",
    data: function(row, type, set, meta){               
       if(!row.hasOwnProperty('c')){
          row.c = row.a + row.b;
       }
       return row.c;
    }
  }]
});
```

See this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpuyq1rg/1/) documentation